# Is anyway to get approved application details for a specific enterprise through android management API?

Tags: android, google-play, android-management-api, android-applicationinfo, android-enterprise

I want to get the list of approved applications for a specific enterprise. As I am using Android Management API, Is there anyway to get it? If not, Is it possible to get it using any third party API's?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is currently no way of getting the approved list of applications for a specific enterprise in Android Management API.

A workaround for this is to create an app that pulls the application policy implemented and then extracting the application IDs. With the extracted application IDs you can use a third party API to fetch the details you need for the approved application(e.g. title, description, etc).

Here’s a [sample code](https://developers.google.com/android/management/sample-app) that you can use as a guideline.

Another way is to manually get the details through [iFrame](https://developers.google.com/android/management/apps#managed_google_play_iframe).